# c# create nested JSON from Model

Tags: json, nested, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create this nested json string in .NET Core2/C# from model but cant quite wrap my head around it:

```
{ 
  \"SearchByKeywordRequest\":
   { 
     \"keyword\": \""+transistor+"\", \"records\": 0, \"startingRecord\": 0, \"searchOptions\": \"string\", \"searchWithYourSignUpLanguage\": \"string\" 
   }
 }
```

I referred to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459097/create-a-nested-json-object-from-c-sharp-model) but couldnt get it to format properly for my case

**Model**

```
 public class SearchByKeyword
{
    public List<SearchByKeyword> SearchByKeywordRequest { get; set; }
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public int records { get; set; } = 10;
    public string searchOptions { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string searchWithYourSignUpLanguage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**Method**

```
public string CreateJson(string transistor) {
        var obj = new SearchByKeyword() {                     
            SearchByKeywordRequest = new List<SearchByKeyword>()
            {
                new SearchByKeyword()
                {
                    keyword = transistor
                }
            }

        };

       return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);  
    }
```

**this is the string i end up with**

```
"{
  \"SearchByKeywordRequest\":
[ { \"SearchByKeywordRequest\":null, \"keyword\":\"KSA992F\",\"records\":10,\"searchOptions\":\"\",\"searchWithYourSignUpLanguage\":\"\"}],\"keyword\":null,\"records\":10,\"searchOptions\":\"\",\"searchWithYourSignUpLanguage\":\"\"
 }"
```

**Now if I try this in method**

```
    var obj = new List<SearchByKeyword>()
            {
                new SearchByKeyword()
                {
                 keyword = transistor
                }
            };
```

**I get this string**

```
"[{\"SearchByKeywordRequest\":null,\"keyword\":\"KSA992F\",\"records\":10,\"searchOptions\":\"\",\"searchWithYourSignUpLanguage\":\"\"}]"
```

**Updated Model**

```
    public class SearchByKeyword
{
    [JsonProperty("SearchByKeywordRequest", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public SearchByKeyword SearchByKeywordRequest { get; set; }
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public int records { get; set; } = 10;   
}
```

**Updated Method**

```
       var obj = new
            {
                SearchByKeywordRequest = new SearchByKeyword()
                {
                    keyword = transistor
                }
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: Do not understand what you expect.The first json does not look like a nested json and what the problem with second json?

Comment: My apologies perhaps it is not nested i'm new to this. The second json doesnt have an open curly bracket after SearchByKeywordRequest, and has a :null. Also the second json is in an array, I am unsure if that matters or not. When I run the json as array in the API UI I get an error.

Comment: Since your type of `SearchByKeywordRequest` is `List<SearchByKeyword>` and it will certainly be serialized to an array. for the `null`, it is becaues it has no children data.You could add `[JsonProperty("SearchByKeywordRequest", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` attribute for `SearchByKeywordRequest`  to bypass it

Comment: I got desired output thanks to your tips. I posted updated code. Removed the lists as they were not necessary.